# Jedi python autocomplete not working

Tags: python-2.7, autocomplete, package, sublimetext3, jedi

I've installed Jedi Python Autocomplete package for Sublime Text 3.

When I installed it, it worked fine.

When I saved a file as `.py` Jedi stop working.

When I restart Sublime Text, Jedi doesn't work.

**Question:** Any suggestions?